# Hive queries through Spark

Tags: scala, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table which is bigger in size (may not fit into a single machine's memory, lets say). The table structure is as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE X
(
id INT,
values ARRAY<INT>
);
```

If i use Scala/Spark to query this table using SparkSQL, **how would the data be distributed across machines in the data frame?**

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc);
val xDF = sqlContext.sql("select id, values from X")
```

Please note that the table X does not have any partitions in it.

I want to process the data further in scala with the following logic,

> 1. There is a set (Y) of integer values (lets say 1,2,3,4,5)
> 2. I want to check if each of these values exist in the values column in the X table (values in xDF)
> 3. Returns a list of values from Y that match with values in X.

**How do i go about doing this?**
I don't want to use collect() on xDf and then execute the above logic as the data may be potentially large. What are my options?